# How to subtract a list from another item by item in NetLogo (like in R)

Tags: list, netlogo, subtraction

EDIT: Should be applicable in NetLogo 5.3.1.

**My problem:**
I have two lists in NetLogo, for example `[13 8 2 20 8]` and `[7 7 7 7 7]` which are both of same length. I want to subract the latter list from earlier item by item, i.e. [(13-7) (8-7) (2-7) (20-7) (8-7)].
Thus the result must be: `[6 1 -5 13 1]`

In R it is very easy:

```
> a <- c(13, 8, 2, 20, 8)
> b <- rep(7, 5)
> c <- a - b
> print(c)
[1]  6  1 -5 13  1
```

Unfortunately, NetLogo does not work in such a convenient way.

**My question:**
How to code this in NetLogo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your lists have the same length you can use `map` to perform operations on multiple lists. The given reporter is then run once for all first items, then once for all second items, ... . The result is then a list of the same length as the input lists.

```
show (map - [13 8 2 20 8] [7 7 7 7 7])
observer: [6 1 -5 13 1]
```

Comment: Agreed. If possible I will delete my answer.